# asp.net mvc5 database cannot be display , its login successfully

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, ef-code-first

I create a database code first in asp.net mvc5 the database its login and register successfully but its not display it app_data (i press on show all files) and server explorer?

Comment: Can you brief the steps you followed ?

Comment: i create a connection string  in webconfg <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefualtConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;
         AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\JobDB.mdf;
         Intital Catalog=JobDB;
         Integrated Security=Ture"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    
  </connectionStrings>  ,, and  its successfully when login

Comment: Please update your question in detail

Answer (score -1):

The first thing you need to do is to configure the connection between your app and your database. If you do this then you need to install entity framework migrations:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx

Code First Migrations has two primary commands that you are going to become familiar with.

`Add-Migration` will scaffold the next migration based on changes you have made to your model since the last migration was created
`Update-Database` will apply any pending migrations to the database.

If you want to create sample data in your database you need to create some database seeder and run it in seed method as follows:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-3

Your question is quite unclear. I don't know what would you like to see in app_data folder.

Comment: If the question is unclear, why did you attempt to answer it? You aren't required to answer every question you see.